# How to view tomcat console logging in eclipse when remote debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I am remote debugging a java web application from eclipse and am trying to view tomcat's console logging in eclipse console so that I dont have to open another tool(NPP or baretail) to view application logs. After doing some research I've found `Ntail` addon which is supposed to show tomcat console logs in eclipse but when I try  installing `Ntail` addon for eclipse luna but its not letting me to install it. I was able to install `Tail Console` but am unable to get to `tail consolse` in eclipse after installing. Can someone help me what is the best addon to view tomcat console logging in eclipse and how do I configure it in eclipse to view tomcat console log?